# Подключение xsd-схемы к xml файлу 2

Tags: xml, xsd

Вроде написала все верно(ошибка - отсутствие требуемого аттрибута country), но ,кажется, что проверки не происходит вовсе, т.е. файл xsd будто бы отсутствует. Но он есть и лежит в той же папке что и xml. Что не так-то?... В смысле, проблема в том, что он нормально отображает все данные, но ведь не должен...
Файл prod.xsd

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="productions">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="production" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
      <xs:complexType>  
          <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"><xs:attribute name ="im" type="xs:string"/></xs:element>
          <xs:element name="songer" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="role" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="year" type="xs:int"/>       
        <xs:attribute name="country" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Файл productions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Подключаем XSLT к XML -->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="t01.xsl"?>
<productions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="prod.xsd">
    <production country="Австрия">
        <name im="Image/songers/beczala.jpg">Don Giovanni</name>
        <songer>Piotr Beczala</songer>
        <role>Don Ottavio</role>
        <year>2006</year>
    </production>
    <production>
        <name im="Image/songers/zaitceva.jpg">Травиата</name>
        <songer>Валерия Зайцева</songer>
        <role>Аннина</role>
        <year>2006</year>
    </production>   
</productions>
```

Comment: А с помощью какого ПО у вас делается валидация?

Comment: Как я понимала вопрос: есть некоторая страничка xml ( для форматирования отображения используется xsl), и файл который должен проверять данные в нем. Не поняла насчет ПО. Единственное "ПО" , которое используется Notepad++ + браузер.....

Comment: вообще говоря, приведённая вами схема `prod.xsd` некорректна; что вам нужно в итоге??

Comment: Можно узнать что вы хотите сделать?

Answer (score 1):

`xsi:schemaLocation` - это когда у схемы пространство имен есть. А вам надо `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` использовать.

Comment: Пробовала, ноль реакции...:(

Comment: Я хоть правильно понимаю, что если поймается ошибка в данных , то  xls их уже не будет выводить?

Comment: @Софья кто вам такое сказал?

Comment: Ок, а как понять , что xsd работает?

Comment: @Софья это надо вас спросить - как вы поняли что он не работает.

Comment: Я прошу прощения, я просто с этой темой не связывалась никогда (не приходилось). А тут резко возникла необходимость....

Comment: если в xml не указать для какой-то записи атрибут country, он все равно выводит все. Или это троль

Comment: @Софья кто - "Он"?

Comment: xml с xsl

Ладно, я понимаю, что чего-то не догоняю... Но реально весь интернет перерыла. В поиске примера... или схожей ситуации. По нулям. Вероятно я не понимаю, как отследить ,что xsd вообще подключился

Comment: @Софья xml - это формат файла, а не программа

Comment: Да, с данными. xsd нужен, чтобы проверить ликвидность этих данных(с тегами?). Нет? Что должно случиться, если данные/теги неверны?

Comment: @Софья где случиться?

Comment: Поздравляю, Вы побаловали свое эго, за счет человека которых хочет, но не может разобраться. Всего хорошего. П,С, Для троллинга найдите равного.

Comment: @Софья почему вы думаете что это троллинг? Я серьезно спрашиваю, чем вы открываете ваш xml и что вы ожидаете увидеть при нарушении схемы. От этого вообще-то зависит ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: @Софья почему вы не можете сказать название программы?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, судя по всему речь идет об открытии xml файла с помощью браузера (см. комментарий под вопросом)

Comment: Возможно, ожидаемый результат был что данные не выведутся в браузер совсем, либо выведутся только те блоки, у которых задан атрибут country (который required). А вопрос заключался в том, какими способами можно проверить что XSD написан корректно. PS: но я тоже ничего не смыслю в XSD :-)

Comment: Да, Uranus ,Вы поняли верно:)